# Drupal Team management

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal (but not in programming)
I'm developing an website with 3 user level.

1. A master one who is able to alter any user content.
2. A medium one who is able to alter his content and the content of users that are registered as his employees.
3. A regular one who is able to alter only his own content.

**A medium user can not alter content from a basic user that is registered under another medium user.**

Researching on google I found Organic Group module. However this module seems to group users according to content type. This is not what I want. It would be more like teams with a leader and members, the teams would publish the same content type.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "master","medium" and "regular" are Drupal roles? By "alter", you mean : edit the content using the default node form?

Comment: If medium user could edit content from all basic users so yes it could be done by simple adding Drupal roles. However medium user can only  edit content from basic user who is bellow him.

Like:
Team A
  medium - Ana
  basic John and Steve
Team B
  medium - Charles
  basic - Mary, George and Leonard.
*************
Ana can edit John and Steve content, but not Mary's

 This is what I'm not being able to do.

Comment: Do you have the module "Field UI" installed? And some "user reference" (or similar "entity reference"...) installed too?

Comment: Field UI is installed. 
User reference I can't find it. Did you mean References ou Entity Reference?
I have Entity Reference installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### User hierarchy

You could use the user fields (/admin/config/people/accounts/fields) to create the hierarchy of user. You could :

1. create a reference to the manager
2. or create many references to the team

[image]

#### Edition security

You could use the [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x). In the implementation of this hook in your module, you'll be able to check if the user can edit the content, or not.

Here is a sample code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    if ($form_id == 'TYPE_node_form') {
    // or if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== false) {

        $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0] ;

        if (! check_if_user_can_edit($user, $node)) {

            drupal_set_message(t('Restricted'), 'error');
            drupal_goto('<front>');
        }
    }
}
```

You `check_if_user_can_edit()` function, should check the `$user` field (team, or whatever), and check also if the owner of `$node` (`$node->uid`), and return `TRUE` if the user is able to edit, or `FALSE` either.

You can also implement the [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) to be sure that no node could be edit in other way, using the same `check_if_user_can_edit()` function.

Comment: Update for `hook_node_presave()`.

Comment: OMG this is genious. I was almost giving up and developing the system in laravel. Now I can see a way out. Thank you so much.